# WinAPI - dialogs: how does disabled main window flash dialog on mouseclick?

Tags: c, winapi, input, dialog, disabled-control

Using WinAPI in C, there are two ways to create a dialog with WinAPI: the more common one is to create a dialog resource in the project's .rc file and then use it with `DialogBox()`, which automates the creation of a standart dialog. The other way is to use `CreateWindowEx` with specific parameters so that the created window acts like a dialog.

An example of dialog creation with `DialogBox` can be seen at winprog.org: http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/dialogs.html

Out of pure interest, I've tried to recreate the dialog created with `DialogBox()`, using `CreateWindowEx`. To do this, I simply disabled the main window and then `CreateWindowEx`'ed the dialog. However, what I got still had one difference from the dialog created with `DialogBox`: when I click on the disabled main window, a `DialogBox`-created dialog flashes (most probably with the `FlashWindowEx` function).

Here's my code for creating a dialog box with `CreateWindowEx`:

```
    HWND hwndParent;

    HINSTANCE ghInstance;

    LPCWSTR g_szDialogClassName = L"DialogClass";

    void populateDialog(HWND hwnd){
        /* Create various dialog controls */
    }

    LRESULT CALLBACK aboutDlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
        switch(Message){
            case WM_CREATE:
                populateDialog(hwnd);
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);

            case WM_COMMAND:
                switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
                    case IDC_CLOSEDLG:
                        EnableWindow(hwndParent, TRUE);
                        DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                        UnregisterClass(g_szDialogClassName, ghInstance);
                    break;
                }
            break;

            case WM_CLOSE:
                EnableWindow(hwndParent, TRUE);
                DestroyWindow(hwnd);
                UnregisterClass(g_szDialogClassName, ghInstance);
            break;

            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    int createDialogBox(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hInstance){
        if (registerClass(hInstance, g_szDialogClassName, (WNDPROC)aboutDlgProc) == 0){
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "Dialog Registration Failed!", "Error!", MB_ICONEXCLAMATION | MB_OK);
            return 0;
        }
        EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE);
        CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, g_szDialogClassName, L"About", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_POPUP | WS_SYSMENU, 100, 100, 450, 150, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

        hwndParent = hwnd;
    }
```

Now I am very interested in how is this done inside `DialogBox()`? How can a disabled window recieve mouse input? Or maybe it wasn't disabled by standart means (by something different than `EnableWindow(hwnd, FALSE)`)? Or is it impossible to reproduce this effect with normal WinAPI calls?

Comment: Please show an MCVE, otherwise we have to guess as to what your code is

Comment: This is code that's baked inside the operating system.  It intercepts the mouse message before it is returned by GetMessage(), flashing the window instead.  You can do this yourself as well with your message loop.  Not with DialogBox() however, the message loop it uses is baked-in as well.

Comment: @HansPassant: so basically, I'd need to process the message before it is processed by GetMessage() in my message loop? How would I do that?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: added my code.

Comment: It looks odd that the window you create has no owner. Surely you need it to be owned by the main window. My guess is that once you do that, you'll be fine. You should also read Raymond Chen's articles on modality: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15696885/why-does-a-messagebox-not-block-the-application-on-a-synchronized-thread/15700193#15700193

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thank you, that solved my problem! Windows actually automates the flash effect if I create the dialog as a child window! You can post this as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you created the window un-owned. Specify the main window as the owner when you call `CreateWindowEx`.

Comment: this is the correct answer! Windows actually automates the flash effect if I create the dialog as a child window! Great thanks! =)

Comment: @Mints97: The operating system automatically flashes an owned window when the user clicks the owner. It does so by calling the [`FlashWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679347.aspx) API.